# Qt SQlite cannot create table

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt

I am trying to have a button click create a table:

```
void summary::on_pushButton_saveSummary_clicked()
{
if(db.open())
    {
        query.exec("create table parrot (total int, defects int, rust int)");
        if (!query.exec())
        {
        qDebug() << query.lastError();
        }
else
{
   qDebug() << db.lastError();
}
}
```

The above produces: QSqlError("1", "Unable to fetch row", "table parrot already exists")
if I make these changes:

```
query.prepare("create table parrot (total int, defects int, rust int)");
query.exec();
```

I get the new error: QSqlError("", "Unable to fetch row", "No query")

```
db.setDatabaseName("/home/igraves/Databases/testdb");
db.open();
```

The above is in the constructor.

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
QSqlQuery query;
```

and the above is in my .h

I have tried every solution to OTHER peoples similar issues, but to no avail. I am hoping someone else has a new idea.

Comment: ***table parrot already exists*** Seems like you should check that.

Comment: use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parrot (total int, defects int, rust int)`

Comment: The db is empty, so there is no table to trigger said event.

Comment: @ig213 How do you create the database? Maybe you've created it somewhere else, check the build folder

Comment: @ellyanesc I am using DB Browser, your answer solved it though.

Comment: @ig213 remove `query.exec("create table parrot (total int, defects int, rust int)");` and change `if (!query.exec())` to `if (!query.exec("create table parrot (total int, defects int, rust int)"))`

Answer (score 0):

@ellanesc was correct, I had tried that solution earlier but had no success, apparently in my frantic rearranging of code, it works now. Thank you!

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parrot (total int, defects int, rust int)
```

The above fixed the problem